# What was the first law that was passed after the formation and acceptance of the Constitution in the United States?

Tags: united-states, history

The Constitution of the United States set forth the procedure whereby laws could be enacted. After the Constitution was accepted by the various states and the proper statesmen were elected, what was the first law they enacted?

Comment: This seems more like a History.SE question than politics.  Would you like me to move it there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first law passed by Congress after the constitution was ratified was [An Act to Regulate the Time and Manner of Administering Certain Oaths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_act_to_regulate_the_time_and_manner_of_administering_certain_oaths). The text of the act can be found [Here](http://memory.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=llsl&fileName=001/llsl001.db&recNum=146). The bill details the manner in which various government officials take an oath to uphold the constitution.